# Writing Regex in Python to Parse Preceding and Succeeding Texts

Tags: python, regex

I am working on parsing XML dumps of English Wikipedia and have got stuck at writing killing regular expression in Python. I am attaching a sample data snippet as follows:

> Amy Jean Klobuchar''' ({{IPAc-en|ˈ|k|l|oʊ|b|ə|ʃ|ɑr}}; born May 25,
>   1960) is the [[Seniority in the United States Senate|senior]] [[United
>   States Senator]] from [[Minnesota]]. She is a member of the
>   [[Minnesota Democratic-Farmer-Labor Party]], an affiliate of the
>   [[Democratic Party (United States)|Democratic Party]]. She is the
>   first woman to be elected as a senator for Minnesota and is one of
>   twenty-one women serving in the current [[United States Senate]].
>
> She previously served as the [[county attorney]] for [[Hennepin
>   County, Minnesota]], the most populous county in Minnesota. As an
>   attorney, she worked with former [[Vice President of the United
>   States|Vice President]] [[Walter Mondale]].{{cite web|
>   author= Senate Web site| title = U.S. Senator for Minnesota Amy
>   Klobuchar: Biography| year = 2007| url=
>   [URL]| accessdate=
>   2007-02-23|archiveurl =
>   [URL]
>   |archivedate = February 21, 2007}} She has been calld a "rising
>   star" in the Democratic Party.{{Cite
>   news|url=[URL]|title=Huffington
>   Post names Klobuchar the smartest U.S.
>   Senator|last=Tsukayama|first=Hayley|date=March 15,
>   2010|work=|access-date=May 14,
>   2017|archive-url=|archive-date=|dead-url=}}{{Cite
>   news|url=[URL]|title=As
>   state's only senator, Klobuchar gains sympathetic
>   attention|last=Dizikes|first=Cynthia|date=May 20,
>   2009|work=MinnPost|access-date=May 14,
>   2017|archive-url=|archive-date=|dead-url=|language=en}}
>
> ==Early life and education==
>
> Born in [[Plymouth, Minnesota]], Klobuchar is the daughter of Rose Katherine (née Heuberger), who
>   retired at age 70 from teaching second grade,{{Cite
>   news|url=[URL]|title=Rose
>   Klobuchar, mother of Sen. Amy Klobuchar,
>   dies|last=Nelson|first=Tim|access-date=2017-02-22}} and [[Jim
>   Klobuchar|James John "Jim" Klobuchar]], an author and a retired
>   sportswriter and columnist for the ''[[Star Tribune]]''.{{Cite
>   news|url=[URL]|title=Born
>   to ride: Jim Klobuchar and the birth of the Minnesota bike
>   tour|newspaper=Star Tribune|access-date=2017-02-22}} Amy has one
>   younger sister. Jim's grandparents were [[Slovene
>   American|Slovene]] immigrants, and his father was a miner on the
>   [[Iron Range]]; Amy's maternal grandparents were from
>   [[Switzerland]].{{cite
>   web|url=[URL]|title=1|work=rootsweb.com|accessdate=11
>   September 2015}}

From this data, I want to parse 1) **ref** tags and **content** between and 2) **section headers**. For instance, ref tags and its content indicate

```
<ref name=bio> 
{{cite web
  |author=Senate Web site
  |title=U.S.Senator for Minnesota Amy Klobuchar: Biography
  |year=2007
  |url=[URL]
  |accessdate=2007-02-23
  |archiveurl=[URL]
  |archivedate = February 21, 2007}}
</ref>
```

whereas a section header means

```
==Early life and education==
```

I've actually succeeded in parsing these fields with following code:

```
import re


LEXEME = [
  ('ref', re.compile(r'<ref[^/>]*>[\s\S]*?</ref>)', 
    re.M | re.I)), 
  ('header', re.compile(r'(^|\n)((==[^=]+==)|(===[^=]+===)|(====[^=]+====))\s*$', 
    re.M | re.I))]

GROUP_RE = re.compile(
  '|'.join('(?P<{0}>{1})'.format(name, regex.pattern) 
    for name, regex in LEXEME), 
  re.M | re.I)


for match in GROUP_RE.finditer(content):
  print(match.lastgroup, '\t', match.group(0), '\n')

# Output
ref  <ref name=bio>{{cite web| author= Senate Web site| title = U.S. Senator for Minnesota Amy Klobuchar: Biography| year = 2007| url= [URL]| accessdate= 2007-02-23|archiveurl = [URL] |archivedate = February 21, 2007}}</ref>
ref  <ref>{{Cite news|url=[URL]|title=Huffington Post names Klobuchar the smartest U.S. Senator|last=Tsukayama|first=Hayley|date=March 15, 2010|work=|access-date=May 14, 2017|archive-url=|archive-date=|dead-url=}}</ref>
ref  <ref>{{Cite news|url=[URL]|title=As state's only senator, Klobuchar gains sympathetic attention|last=Dizikes|first=Cynthia|date=May 20, 2009|work=MinnPost|access-date=May 14, 2017|archive-url=|archive-date=|dead-url=|language=en}}</ref>
header  ==Early life and education==
```

I want to expand the current regex so that I can also get preceding and succeeding texts of up to 250 characters when parsing ref tags and its content.
For example, I want to get

```
She previously served as the [[county attorney]] for [[Hennepin County, Minnesota]], the most populous county in Minnesota. As an attorney, she worked with former [[Vice President of the United States|Vice President]] [[Walter Mondale]].
<ref name=bio>
{{cite web
  |author=Senate Web site
  |title=U.S. Senator for Minnesota Amy Klobuchar: Biography
  |year=2007
  |url=[URL]
  |accessdate=2007-02-23
  |archiveurl=[URL] 
  |archivedate=February 21, 2007}}
</ref>
She has been called a "rising star" in the Democratic Party.<ref>{{Cite news|url=[URL]|title=Huffington Post names Klobuchar the smartest U.S
```

instead of

```
<ref name=bio>
{{cite web
  |author=Senate Web site
  |title=U.S. Senator for Minnesota Amy Klobuchar: Biography
  |year=2007
  |url=[URL]
  |accessdate=2007-02-23
  |archiveurl=[URL] 
  |archivedate=February 21, 2007}}
</ref>
```

So, I modified my code as follows:

```
LEXEME = [
  ('ref', re.compile(r'([\s\S]{1,250})(<ref[^/>]*>[\s\S]*?</ref>)([\s\S]{1,250}))', 
    re.M | re.I)), 
  ('header', re.compile(r'(^|\n)((==[^=]+==)|(===[^=]+===)|(====[^=]+====))\s*$', 
    re.M | re.I))]
```

Some problems arise

1) when multiple ref tags occur consecutively at the end of a sentence:

```
<ref>{{Cite
news|url=[URL]|title=Huffington
Post names Klobuchar the smartest U.S.
Senator|last=Tsukayama|first=Hayley|date=March 15,
2010|work=|access-date=May 14,
2017|archive-url=|archive-date=|dead-url=}}</ref><ref>{{Cite
news|url=[URL]|title=As
state's only senator, Klobuchar gains sympathetic
attention|last=Dizikes|first=Cynthia|date=May 20,
2009|work=MinnPost|access-date=May 14,
2017|archive-url=|archive-date=|dead-url=|language=en}}</ref>
```

The anticipated result was

```
ref  up-to-250-chars<ref>content</ref>up-to-250-chars
ref  up-to-250-chars<ref>content</ref>up-to-250-chars
```

However, the code only captures the latter ref tags and related preceding/succeeding texts.

2) when section heading appears in succeeding text. ref regex captures the header as succeeding text and header regex is skipped as follows.

```
ref  s-date=May 14,
2017|archive-url=|archive-date=|dead-url=|language=en}}</ref>

==Early life and education== Born in [[Plymouth, Minnesota]], Klobuchar is the daughter of Rose Katherine (née Heuberger), who
retired at age 70 from teaching second grade,<ref>{{Cite
news|url=[URL]|title=Rose
Klobuchar, mother of Sen. Amy Klobuchar,
dies|last=Nelson|first=Tim|access-date=2017-02-22}}</ref> and [[Jim
Klobuchar|James John "Jim" Klobuchar]], an author and a retired
sportswriter and columnist for the ''[[Star Tribune]]''.<ref>{{Cite
news|url=[URL]
```

I wonder how I can tackle this issue.

Happy coding!

Comment: Blockquote doesn't allow me to user <ref> and </ref> as text. Please assume any {{cite ... }} is aurrounded by <ref> and </ref> in the sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is (probably) possible with regex by making use of [lookarounds](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html#lookahead-assertions), it's a lot easier to just use string operations:

```
for match in GROUP_RE.finditer(content):
    start= max(0, match.start()-250)
    end= min(len(content), match.end()+250)
    matched_text= content[start:end]
```

Comment: OMG, it could've been much simpler than I thought! Appreciated it a lot, @Rawing!